# Пытаюсь сделать появляющееся, пропадающее меню на jquery

Tags: jquery, меню

Собственно при клике картинка меняется меню появляется, а вот обратно после второго клика не работает.

```js
function openm() {
 if (this.src = '/menu-icon.png') {
                jQuery('.navbar-brand').css('visibility','visible');
                jQuery('.site-header-menu').css('visibility','visible');
                jQuery('.meun').attr('src','/x.png');
 } 
 else  {
                jQuery('.navbar-brand').css('visibility','hidden');
                jQuery('.site-header-menu').css('visibility','hidden');
                jQuery('.meun').attr('src','/menu-icon.png');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: html забыли добавить к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто, у Вас ошибка в условии if. Сейчас Вы **присваиваете** this.src значение '/menu-icon.png', результат приводится к `true`. Второй раз когда вы кликаете - происходит всё то же самое и результат тот же возвращается. Нужно:

```
if (this.src == '/menu-icon.png') {
```